# SSIS - Process a flat file with varying data

Tags: ssis

I have to process a flat file whose syntax is as follows, one record per line.

```
<header>|<datagroup_1>|...|<datagroup_n>|[CR][LF]
```

The header has a fixed-length field format that never changes (ID, timestamp etc). However, there are different types of data groups and, even though fixed-length, the number of their fields vary depending on the data group type. The three first numbers of a data group define its type. The number of data groups in each record varies also.

My idea is to have a staging table with to which I would insert all the data groups. So two records like this,

```
12320160101|12323456KKSD3467|456SSGFED43520160101173802|
98720160102|456GGLWSD45960160108854802|
```

Would produce three records in the staging table.

```
ID   Timestamp   Data
123  01/01/2016  12323456KKSD3467
123  01/01/2016  456SSGFED43520160101173802
987  02/01/2016  456GGLWSD45960160108854802
```

This would allow me to preprocess the staged records for further processing (some would be discarded, some have their data broken down further). My question is how to break down the flat file into the staging table. I can split the entire record with pipe (|) and then use a Derived Column Transformation to break down the header with SUBSTRING. After that it gets trickier because of the varying number of data groups.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with myself doesn't try to split at the flat file source, but rather in a script. My Data Flow looks like this.

[image]

So the Flat File Source output is just a single column containing the entire line. The Script Component contains output columns for each column in the Staging table. The script looks like this.

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    var splits = Row.Line.Split('|');

    for (int i = 1; i < splits.Length; i++)
    {
        Output0Buffer.AddRow();
        Output0Buffer.ID = splits[0].Substring(0, 11);
        Output0Buffer.Time = DateTime.ParseExact(splits[0].Substring(14, 14), "yyyyMMddHHmmssFFF", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Output0Buffer.Datagroup = splits[i];
    }
}
```

Note that in the SynchronousInputID property (Script Transformation Editor > Input and Outputs > Output0) must be set to None. Otherwise you won't have Output0Buffer available in your script. Finally the OLE DB Destination just maps the script output columns to the Staging table columns. This solves the problem I had with creating multiple output Records from a single input record.